# Manipulate with pre-assigned number of parameter

Tags: manipulate

My goal is to draw dots whose positions can be adjusted. I could draw a fixed number of dots, say 2 and 5, like the code below. If the user sets the number of dots, how do I create dots and sliders according to that number?

```
Manipulate[
 NumberLinePlot[{a, b}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 4}], {{a, 1.5}, 0, 4}, {{b, 1}, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 NumberLinePlot[{a, b, c, d, e}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 4}], {{a, 1.5}, 0, 4}, {{b, 1}, 0, 4}, {{c, 1.2}, 
  0, 4}, {{d, 1.3}, 0, 4}, {{e, 1.4}, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a nested `Manipulate`:

```
DynamicModule[{numbers},
 Manipulate[
  Manipulate[
   NumberLinePlot[Lookup[numbers, Range[n], 0],
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}],
   Column[
    Slider[Dynamic[numbers[#]], {0, 5}] & /@ Range[n]
    ]
   ],
  {n, 1, 10, 1},
  Initialization :> (numbers = <||>)
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Clever. Where did you find that the controls are placed in an association by specifying: `Initialization :> (numbers = <||>`

Comment: @DanielHuber I don't remember, but when you have something like `Slider[Dynamic[expr], ...]`, you get a control that continuously evaluates `expr = controlSetting`. So if the expression points to the part of an association or a list, it just uses `Part` assignment like it normally does.